# Can we send a notification to a blackberry mobile without using AppId?

Tags: c#, php, blackberry

i was wondering if we can send a notification to a blackberry device based on his Pin and without using a application ID ?

I did some researches and i found that i always need a App ID .

I'm making a server side application to send those notification. I don't care what language does it use. I just need it to work as i need !

Some of the blogs that i checked that need App Id to work are :
[Here](http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/search/label/Push%20Notification) and [here](http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/search/label/Push%20Notification)

So do i miss something ? Anyway to send Notification to 1 device based on his Pin only ?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a corporate application being used for devices running on the corporate BES?

Comment: No its for self use, anyway i just found that there is no way to send notification based on blackberry Pin (that was the old way to send notification) now we need Application ID
Thanks anyway !

Comment: without the app id, you cant send notification to device. You already checked my blog. There i mentioned that for push message, you need app id.